# Divs expanding the site and won't align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My problem is that I can not make my sidebar and a table align vertically. They make the body have a longer width and won't stand side by side. I have tried given the table a style of `float: left` but that still made the site expand and didn't look that well. 
I am using Bootstrap, CSS, HTML and would like to get a solution within these limits.
See the picture for a better understanding:

[image: sidebar and table]

```css
sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sidebar .list-group {
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: #333;
    min-height: 80vh ;
}
#sidebar i {
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-color: #2c2c2c;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* highlight active menu */
#sidebar .list-group-item:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: #222;
}

/* closed state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* open state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #222;
}
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* level 1*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapsing .list-group-item  {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* level 2*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapsing .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* level 3*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 35px;
        max-width: 40px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: visible;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transform: translateX(-45px);
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    #sidebar.show {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    #sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0px; }
    
    #sidebar, #sidebar .list-group {
        min-width: 35px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.show, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
        top: 0;
    }
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
}

.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapsing {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.holder {
    background-image: url(bg-imgZ.jpg);
    height: 90vh;
    background-size: cover; 
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    /*
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    */
}

.holder{
text-align: center;
}

.holder .content h1{
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.holder .arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 120px; 
    margin-left: -6px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.table {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.table #head {
    color: #FFF;
}

#h2 {
   margin-left: 390px;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#headertxt h1{
  margin-left: 320px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="holder">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
                    
                    <!-- Brand -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                    
                    <!-- Links -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">   
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FFB400; font-size:20px;font-weight: bold;" href="#">Mining</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donate</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Cryptocrea</h1>
        <!--<p>-Cryptocurrentcy mining made easy!</p>-->
    </div>
    
    <a class="arrow"><img class="animated bounce" src="arrow_C.png" id="scroll"></a>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="toggle.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9" id="headertxt"><h1>Crypto</h1>
 <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

  </div>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width show" id="sidebar">
                <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">
                <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 1</span> </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
                    <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 5 e </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub2">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 3</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 2</span></a>
                <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 3 </span></a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu3">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.1</a>
                    <a href="#menu3sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">3.2 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu3sub2">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 b</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 c</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.3</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 4</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 5</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
            
            </div>
        </div>
       
                    
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need the sidebar fixed to the left side of your screen or just left to the table?

Comment: The problem isn't that your sidebar is in the wrong place, it's that your `data-target` isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your html you are getting overly keen with using classes e.g. rows and columns to organise your data on screen. The over over-application of classes will come to haunt you with various CSS bugs so as a nit pick I'd try to keep the number of classes you apply to elements fairly low (but that's only my opinion)

Take a look at [flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) which is a neat alternative to using floats and a lot more intuitive.

> The Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module (currently a W3C Last Call Working Draft) aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out, align and distribute space among items in a container, even when their size is unknown and/or dynamic (thus the word "flex").

TIP: [Useful Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**TLDR SOLUTION:**

*Add flex to the outer container:*

```
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
}
```

*Add all items you want next to each other inside that container:*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="item1"> ITEM 1 CONTENT </div>
  <div class="item2"> ITEM 2 CONTENT </div>
</div>
```

**FULL SOLUTION:**

```css
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
}

sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sidebar .list-group {
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: #333;
    min-height: 80vh ;
}
#sidebar i {
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-color: #2c2c2c;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* highlight active menu */
#sidebar .list-group-item:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: #222;
}

/* closed state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* open state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #222;
}
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* level 1*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapsing .list-group-item  {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* level 2*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapsing .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* level 3*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 35px;
        max-width: 40px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: visible;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transform: translateX(-45px);
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    #sidebar.show {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    #sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0px; }
    
    #sidebar, #sidebar .list-group {
        min-width: 35px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.show, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
        top: 0;
    }
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
}

.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapsing {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.holder {
    background-image: url(bg-imgZ.jpg);
    height: 90vh;
    background-size: cover; 
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    /*
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    */
}

.holder{
text-align: center;
}

.holder .content h1{
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.holder .arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 120px; 
    margin-left: -6px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.table {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.table #head {
    color: #FFF;
}

#h2 {
   margin-left: 390px;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#headertxt h1{
  margin-left: 320px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="holder">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
                    
                    <!-- Brand -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                    
                    <!-- Links -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">   
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FFB400; font-size:20px;font-weight: bold;" href="#">Mining</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donate</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Cryptocrea</h1>
        <!--<p>-Cryptocurrentcy mining made easy!</p>-->
    </div>
    
    <a class="arrow"><img class="animated bounce" src="arrow_C.png" id="scroll"></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width show" id="sidebar">
                <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">
                <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 1</span> </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
                    <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 5 e </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub2">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 3</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 2</span></a>
                <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 3 </span></a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu3">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.1</a>
                    <a href="#menu3sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">3.2 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu3sub2">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 b</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 c</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.3</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 4</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 5</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
            
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <div id="headertxt"><h1>Crypto</h1>
 <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this solution was what you were looking for!

PS: Worth coding your HTML in an IDE to keep your code inline and match up all your tags. Take a look at [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) if you haven't used it before